# Why a public static method is not accessible?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to reflect the `parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)` methods from classes which each extends the `TemporalAccessor` class.

```java
    private static final Map<Class<?>, MethodHandle> PARSE_HANDLES = synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    static <T extends TemporalAccessor> MethodHandle parseMethodHandle(final Class<T> clazz) {
        if (clazz == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("clazz is null");
        }
        return PARSE_HANDLES.computeIfAbsent(clazz, k -> {
            try {
                final Method method = clazz.getMethod("parse", CharSequence.class, DateTimeFormatter.class);
                log.debug("method: {}, {}", method, method.isAccessible());
                // i don't understand; public static method is not accessible? yet it isn't.
                assert method.isAccessible(); // NOT GOOD with UTs
                return MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(method);
            } catch (final ReflectiveOperationException roe) {
                throw new RuntimeException(roe);
            }
        });
    }
```

With the `YearMonth` class, I got this.

```
method: public static java.time.YearMonth java.time.YearMonth.parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter), false
```

Why a `public static` method is not accessible?

Comment: what "public static" method? I see a default static method.

Comment: Error message concerns [public static YearMonth parse(CharSequence text,                        DateTimeFormatter formatter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the documentation for `isAccessible`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#isAccessible()):

> This method is deprecated because its name hints that it checks if the reflected object is accessible when it actually indicates if the checks for Java language access control are suppressed. **This method may return `false` on a reflected object that is accessible to the caller.** To test if this reflected object is accessible, it should use [`canAccess(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#canAccess(java.lang.Object)).

*(My emphasis.)*

Answer (score 1):

With the Java Reflection API, you can override the accessibility of methods by setting the *accessible*  flag. This can be performed by `method.setAccessible(true)`.

Now the `isAccessible()` method does not what you think it does, but it simply checks, if the standard java access checks are currently overridden.

This means, that you can of course invoke the method with reflection if the standard access modifiers allow it. Otherwise, you had to set the *accessible* flag.